# samples[i-1] not populating in for loop for Markov-Chain Monte Carlo using Metropolis?

Tags: r, for-loop, montecarlo, markov-chains

I'm trying to produce a function in R for Markov-Chain Monte Carlo sampling based on the Metropolis Algorithm. The function needs to accept as arguments a target density function (PDF), a function to propose the next step, a starting point, and the number of steps to evaluate. The output should be a vector with length equal to the number of steps.

The problem is that I get multiple warnings when trying to use the function:
`In rnorm(1, x, 0.5) : NAs produced`

I think that the issue might be that the way I am trying to define the current step: `samples[i-1]` does not return a value. I am not sure why this is. I have set `samples[1]` to be the starting point entered into the function, and then for `i in 2:samples.n`, `samples[i-1]` should return the previous value, shouldn't it?

I've tried using the function `propose` on its own, and it works fine. This led me to believe that the issue was the input `samples[i-1]` for the function `propose` in the for loop.

```
PDF.beta <- function(x) dbeta(x, 12, 6)

propose <- function(x) rnorm(1, x, 0.5)

MCMC.sample <- function(target.PDF, prop.func, startx, samples.n) {
  samples <- numeric()
  samples[1] <- startx
  for(i in 2:samples.n)
    {
    proposed.step <- prop.func(samples[i-1])
    ifelse(runif(1) < target.PDF(proposed.step)/target.PDF(samples[i-1]),
      samples[i] <- proposed.step,
      samples[i] <- samples[i-1])
  }
  return(samples)
}


beta.MCMC <- MCMC.sample(target.PDF = PDF.beta, prop.func = propose, startx = 4, samples.n = 1000)
```

I expect to see a vector of length `samples.n` produced from the function `MCMC.sample` given the inputs in `beta.MCMC`. Instead, the output of `samples` is just one value: 4, which is what I input to be my starting value. I also get the many error messages: `In rnorm(1, x, 0.5) : NAs produced`.

Comment: `samples` is of length one, it should be `samples.n + 1`. Try replacing the first line of the `MCMC.sample` body with `samples <- numeric(length=samples.n + 1)`.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This is a lifesaver. I ended up using just `samples <- numeric(length=samples.n)` instead of length=samples.n +1 because adding +1 would give an output of 1001 if I used the argument samples.n = 1000.

Comment: True, but the first one wouldn't be a sample, would it? Or maybe you'd count that as burn-in.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a proper answer for completeness.

The main issue was that `samples` wasn't of the proper length, but I ended up rewriting parts of the function because it didn't appear to me well defined what should happen when `target.PDF(proposed.step)/target.PDF(samples[i-1])` return `NaN`

```
MCMC.sample <- function(target.PDF, prop.func, startx, samples.n) {
  samples <- numeric(length=samples.n)
  samples[1] <- startx
  for(i in 2:(samples.n)) {
    proposed.step <- prop.func(samples[i-1])
    target.r <- runif(1) < target.PDF(proposed.step)/target.PDF(samples[i-1])
    samples[i] <- ifelse(
      is.na(target.r) | target.r,
      proposed.step, 
      samples[i-1])
  }
  samples
}

set.seed(1)
beta.MCMC <- MCMC.sample(PDF.beta, propose, 4, 1000)

plot(beta.MCMC, type="l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the problem is when the denominator of the target distribution quotient is very small, the quotient is very big. The way to handle this is to set the quotient equal to 1.0 with an `if` statement when the routine produces a quotient greater than 1.0 (ie the denominator is very small), and then generate the random number.